# ASP.NET MVC Validation change color from red to green on success

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have successfully implemented the validation for all my fields using the data annotations, but now what i want is that when the value entered in my field is valid , i want its color to change from Red which comes by default to green indicating it as a success.

Any idea on this..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your default css file there are following codes:

```
/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error
{
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid
{
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error
{
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid
{
    display: none;
}
```

You can change where you want.

Comment: I was expecting this to change the field border but it did nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Jquery automatically adds valid class after you change the input from error to valid so simply add style for it

CSS:

```
input.valid
{
    border: 1px solid Green;
}
```